# no hiddenfields in intraweb?

Tags: hidden-field, intraweb

Seems that Intraweb 14.0.42 does not generate anymore hidden fields.
I define one or more of them in the "HiddenFields" stringlist
but they are not generated on the page.

Is this true ?

Thanks.

Maurizio.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your IWForm' `RenderInvisibleControls` property is set to `true`